# IBatis how to execute multi queries in once call

Tags: mysql, spring, ibatis

I am using IBatis and Spring framework.

I would like to execute multi queries but I could not get the response.

```
<select id="getUIs" resultMap="blpUiVOMap" parameterClass="Map">
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('COUNT(CASE WHEN bug.BUG_STT = ', STT_ID, ' THEN 1 END) AS ''bugI', STT_ID, '''')
      ) INTO @sql
    from BLP_STT <![CDATA[;]]>

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ui.UI_ID, ui.UI_NM, cat.CAT_ID, cat.CAT_NM, cat.PRNT_ID, cat1.CAT_NM as PRNT_NM,',@sql,'FROM BLP_UI ui JOIN BLP_CAT cat ON ui.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID JOIN BLP_CAT cat1 ON cat.PRNT_ID = cat1.CAT_ID JOIN BLP_BUG bug ON ui.UI_ID = bug.UI_ID JOIN BLP_STT stt ON bug.BUG_STT = stt.STT_ID WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY ui.UI_ID ORDER BY ui.UI_ID ASC') <![CDATA[;]]>

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql <![CDATA[;]]>
    EXECUTE stmt <![CDATA[;]]>
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt <![CDATA[;]]>
</select>
```

In MySQL, this query is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `<select>` will create a single `PreparedStatement` in JDBC. You are trying to execute commands from the MySQL command line. This won't work in JDBC or MyBatis.

You will need to create a single query that combines all your strings. Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT ui.UI_ID, ui.UI_NM, cat.CAT_ID, cat.CAT_NM, cat.PRNT_ID, cat1.CAT_NM as PRNT_NM,
(SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT('COUNT(CASE WHEN bug.BUG_STT = ', STT_ID, ' THEN 1 END) AS ''bugI', STT_ID, '''')
  )
  from BLP_STT
)
FROM BLP_UI ui JOIN BLP_CAT cat ON ui.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID JOIN BLP_CAT cat1 ON cat.PRNT_ID = cat1.CAT_ID JOIN BLP_BUG bug ON ui.UI_ID = bug.UI_ID JOIN BLP_STT stt ON bug.BUG_STT = stt.STT_ID WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY ui.UI_ID ORDER BY ui.UI_ID ASC')
```

Note, you also do not need to put a `;` in the XML either.